# How can I fix my menu so it isn't possible for the user to scroll when it's active?

Tags: html, css, menu

I want to make it impossible to scroll when the menu is active. I've tried to add a position: fixed at several places but it will mess everything up. Random elements will join the menu. I've also tried to ad an extra container around the menu but that doesn't work as well. Does anyone know how I can fix this? It would really help me, thank you so much in advance.

```js
// Navbar
const hamburger_menu = document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu");
const nav_container = document.querySelector(".nav-container");

hamburger_menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nav_container.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
/* Nav */

.nav-container {
  min-height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, var(--primary-color) 0%, #b8b8b8 74%);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 3rem;
}

.menu {
  max-width: 72rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--white-smoke)
}

.logo {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  line-height: 4rem;
}

.logo span {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  height: 4rem;
  width: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.bar {
  width: 1.9rem;
  height: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: var(--white-smoke);
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: relative;
}

.bar:before,
.bar:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: var(--white-smoke);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.bar:before {
  transform: translateY(-9px);
}

.bar:after {
  transform: translateY(9px);
}

.nav-container .nav-main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-container.active .bar {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-container.active .bar:before {
  transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-container.active .bar:after {
  transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-container.active .nav-main {
  animation: main-animation 0.5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.5);
}

@keyframes main-animation {
  from {
    transform: translate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.5);
  }
}

.nav-links {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 90vh;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-links a {
  padding: 0.7rem 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  animation: hide 0.5s forwards ease;
}

.nav-container.active .nav-links a {
  animation: appear 0.5s forwards ease var(--i);
}

@keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}

.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.shadow.one {
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.shadow.two {
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.nav-container.active .shadow.one {
  animation: shadow-one 0.6s ease-out;
  transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(215px) scale(0.5);
}

@keyframes shadow-one {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0);
  }
  5% {
    transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(215px) scale(0.5);
  }
}

.nav-container.active .shadow.two {
  animation: shadow-two 0.6s ease-out;
  transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.5);
}

@keyframes shadow-two {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(310px) scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(120px) scale(0.5);
  }
}

.nav-container.active .nav-main:hover+.shadow.one {
  transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(230px) scale(0.5);
}

.nav-container.active .nav-main:hover {
  transform: perspective(1300px) rotateY(20deg) translateZ(340px) scale(0.5);
}
```

````html
<!-- Nav -->
<div class="nav-container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="index.html">
        <h3 class="logo">Otopoets Galerie</h3>
      </a>
      <div class="hamburger-menu">
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-main-container">
    <div class="nav-main">
      <header>
        <div class="index-header">
          <div class="index-header-content">
            <div class="index-header-text">
              <h1>Neem contact met ons op</h1>
              <p class="small">Passion and experience lead to quality...</p>
            </div>

            <a href="#" class="btn"><span></span>Afspraak inplannen</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>

    <div class="shadow one"></div>
    <div class="shadow two"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-links">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html" style="--i: 0.05s;">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="pakketten.html" style="--i: 0.1s;">Poetspakketten</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="projecten.html" style="--i: 0.15s;">Projecten</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="overons.html" style="--i: 0.2s;">Over ons</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact.html" style="--i: 0.25s;">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>



```
````

Comment: Take a look [overflow:hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Answer (score 1):

To prevent user from scrolling, you toggle a class `no-scroll` on the `body` in your event:

```js
const hamburger_menu = document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu");
const nav_container = document.querySelector(".nav-container");
const body = document.querySelector("body");

hamburger_menu.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav_container.classList.toggle("active");
    body.classList.toggle("no-scroll");
});
```

```css
.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```